# Dynamically update Lightning path (Chevron)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

My Lightning/Salesforce Path was displaying the Chevron based on the Case Pick list field which has 15 pick list options. Every Case is unique and doesn't require all the 15 options, how can I make my Chevron dynamic with limited options.

i.e Case 1 needs 5 pick list options out of 15 then I need to show only 5 options in 5 the chevron.

Comment: How are you "uniquely identifying" your Cases? Are you referring here standard Lightning Experience or you are building anything using custom Lightning Component?

Comment: Jayanth - I am referring standard lightning experience here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps to be able to display only relevant picklist information on Path component for particular Case, only when you:

1. Define Case Record Types
2. Define available picklist values for each record type
3. Setup Path for every record type

Comment: Jayanth - The pick list values will be determined during the run time.  i.e The total pick list options required for the Case workflow will be determined during run time.

Comment: That’s still fine. As long as you classify a Case with a record type, which gets evaluated at runtime, the approach will still work. Not completely aware of your use case here, but this is the standard no code approach that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I have go custom chevron path here. A Case will end up with any combination out of 15! possibilities.